# How to group dates by periods of n days in R?

Tags: r, date

###### Input

```r
dates <- as.Date(c("2022-01-20", "2022-01-30", "2022-01-31", "2022-02-10"))
n     <- 10 # number of days for each period
```

###### Output

```r
group <- c(1, 2, 2, 3)
```

Group `1` corresponds to the earliest date and dates that are in a period of `n - 1` days at most after the earliest date of the vector.

One could convert each date to its number of days (since when 1900?) and use the `%/%` operator but I want a more proper solution.

Another solution would be to use `seq(min(dates), max(dates), by = "10 days")` but I can't manage to find such a way to achieve the output.

Comment: Can you explain what the `group` means here?

Comment: I sorted the dates, so it's clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```r
dates <- as.Date(c("2022-01-20", "2022-01-30", "2022-01-31", "2022-02-10"))
n     <- 10 # number of days for each period

as.integer(factor(as.integer(dates) %/% n))
#> [1] 1 2 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or with `findInterval`.

```r
findInterval(dates, seq(min(dates), max(dates), by = "10 days"))
#> [1] 1 2 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Please note that the `factor` alternative just creates a consecutive group number irrespective of the number of days that have elapsed. Try e.g. `as.Date(c("2022-01-20", "2022-02-20", "2022-04-20"))`. Cheers

Comment: @Henrik That's why the solution with `findInterval` is better